# Can anyone help me how to insert the same id in different tables

Tags: php, sql, opencart

How to insert the same id in different tables at a time in one table. it is a primary key and autoincrement and in another table. It is a foreign key at a time. I have to insert in both the tables using OpenCrat.

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " 
. DB_PREFIX .   "xyz
SET 
    boutiques_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "',
    boutique_customer_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['boutique_customer_id']) . "',
    ordered_date = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ordered_date']) . "',
  '");

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " 
. DB_PREFIX .   "abc 
SET 
    boutiques_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "',
    firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', 
    lastname        = '" .$this->db->escape($data['lastname']). "',

    }
```

in abc  table it is a primary key and autoincrement whereas in second table it is foreign key.

Comment: i didnt get u can u show the code once.

Answer (score 2):

After an insert query use this `$this->db->getLastId();` to get last inserted id of that table, by this u can add this to another table.

Answer (score 0):

The ghetto way assuming there is a unique constraint on boutique_customer_id and ordered_date would be:

```
INSERT INTO abc (boutiques_id, firstname, lastname)
SELECT boutiques_id, 'John', 'Smith'
FROM xyz
WHERE boutique_customer_id = 123
AND ordered_date = 2015-05-01
```

Or else you would need to use a transaction/programmatically get and set that foreign key value. Either way I wouldn't try to set the primary key when initially inserting. Finally unrelated to your question, try looking at using an ORM.

Comment: In a single function we are inserting both the tables